# Velocity of an object in a decaying orbit

Tags: orbital-motion

The velocity of an object in a stable orbit is well known and (relatively) easy to derive.  I have a problem involving a decaying orbit.  An object, M2, in a vacuum is orbiting another object, M1, but it's orbit is decaying by a given distance on each orbit.

[image]

I need a foruma that will tell me what is the tangential velocity of the body, M2, given M1, M2, G, r and the decay of each orbit (delta x).

Comment: To get your expression you need to know where the orbital energy is 'leaking'. For decay to happen there must be some opposing force with momentum transfer. If it's not molecules in the upper reaches of the atmosphere (you say vacuum - hard vacuum?) then what do you propose as the sapping force?

Comment: Orbits don't decay in a vacuum. You can have energy loss, for example due to tides in the body being orbitted, but that makes the orbit increase in radius not decrease. As it stands your question can't be answered because it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @JohnRennie, orbital increases are not guaranteed.  It depends on the specifics.  Tidal decay on objects below geosync altitude (such as Phobos and Mars) or on retrograde orbits would cause altitude decrease.

Comment: @JohnRennie - BowlOfRed has the general idea, however, your question raises a more interesting question: how do galaxies accrete?  Let's assume that the gasses that gave rise to the Milky Way once were much, much larger than the current 100,000 Light Year diameter.  How does any mass outside of the current 50 kLy radius accrete if there is no loss of kinetic energy?

Comment: @DonaldRoyAirey: two effects (a) [dynamical friction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamical_friction) (b) conversion of kinetic energy to heat during collisions - the heat then escapes by radiation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have some sort of slow, continuous drag on the object, then velocity at any point is equal to the velocity of a circular orbit at that point.  The object doesn't have a single speed from the start to the end of your graphic, but a slowly increasing one.

As the drag occurs, the slowing of the object and the loss of altitude happen simultaneously.  The two effects combine to raise the tangential speed.

If the drag is non-continuous, then you have to account for orbital eccentricities that make it more challenging.